# How to indicate a search directory different than the current one in grep

Tags: grep

How do I run a grep on the "c:\Test" directory from "c:\Users\myName?
I tried with grep c:\Test text -r but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the string that you would like to grep in your command then the file, the syntax for grep is `grep <string> <file path>`

lets say I'm in the `home` directory that contains a sub-directory called `test` with a couple text files inside it:

```
file1.txt: hello world
file2.txt: the quick brown fox had entered the world

etc...
```

if I was grepping the word "world" from the `home` directory I would type this

```
grep world test/*
```

the "*" character just means search all files.